# On loading the application in IE 11 it throws error on console saying - SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'fn' of undefined or null reference

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'fn' of undefined or null reference 
bootstrap.min.js (6,2004)

I am using

`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

And my application is Angular4 based

Comment: load jquery script before this bootstrap script

Comment: Thanks I think I might have made this blunder , I'll check and update, but it works fine on chrome

Comment: @MukeshKumar Thanks that resolved my issue , after resolving this, one more error I get= SCRIPT5009: 'System' is undefined, in IE so what might be the issue, please could you guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load jQuery script before your Bootstrap script. Hopefully, this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks that resolved my issue , after resolving this, one more error I get= SCRIPT5009: 'System' is undefined, in IE11 so what might be the issue, please could you guide me

Comment: Please uncomment all polyfills in polyfills.ts file.

Comment: Yeah they are uncommented , one more thing i might have missed out is doing npm install --save classlist.js, that I am doing , apart from polyfills what else can be the reason , if you could point out, Thanks

Comment: I don't know the exact solution of this issue but you can find a related question in this link: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7144

Comment: Hi @Mukeshkumar , sorry for commenting here again , that is not causing an issue as such what I found is there is another error SCRIPT1002: Syntax Error vendor.bundle.js(8315,1) and it has eval function, I have seen a similar question Stackoverflow but it has not answer as such, any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Add this line in index.html file under HEAD tag.
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />